# Safely adding a customizable "tracking code" field to php web application

Tags: javascript, php, html, security

I have a small web application written in vanilla PHP with MySQL database, on which registered users are able to create custom profile pages.

Id like to add a textarea form field in the control panel, for users to add their custom tracking code (namely Facebook Pixel or Google Analytics) for their tracking purposes.

My question is, what is the correct way to add such functionality? I'm afraid letting my users to "inject" custom code would lead to security issues for my website. As far as i know the aforementioned tracking codes use regular JS/HTML for their tracking. If that is the case how to allow JS while restricting server side code, like PHP, from being executed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tracking code is always the same, apart from one or two elements. For instance, in a Google Tracking code the only variable element is a tracking ID in the format: `UA-XXXXX-Y`.

You could let the user select which type of tracking they want and let them only enter the tracking ID, and perhaps one more variable. You can easily check whether these have been entered in the correct format. From that you can generate the Javascript code yourself.

Alternatively, now that you know the code is always the same you could also use that to check what has been entered. Strip out any non-linguistical elements like space, and check it against your template: Only the ID's should be variable and you know their format.

However, I think this last method is less user-friendly, because it relies on the users to provide you with a rather exact copy of the code. That might be too difficult, and that will be your problem.